# Call stored procedure with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I want to call stored procedure from PostgreSQL with hibernate. But, if i call this procedure throught entitymanager.getResultList, it's return me a list of objects with strange names of attributes.
Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.show_top10()
  RETURNS SETOF users
AS
$BODY$
  SELECT * FROM users
    ORDER BY message_count DESC
    LIMIT 10;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

User's atributes:

```
private Integer id;
private String login;
private String password;
private Timestamp dateCreated;
private Long messageCount;
private Integer role;
private Collection<Message> messagesById;
```

Calling:

```
List<Users> result = null;
            StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery= entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("show_top10");
            storedProcedureQuery.execute();
            result = storedProcedureQuery.getResultList();
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

And result:

[image: result]

Comment: Use a `select` statement instead: `select * from show_top10()`. I don't know Hibernate, but there must be a way to run a plain select in a similar way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you expect?
Your SP is returning `ResultSet` from `SELECT` query, 10 records.
SQL by itself only returns values, **not** field names...

Further more - **why** do you create a SQL function that returns a `ResultSet`?

Comment: So, how i can return table with rows of table users ?

Comment: If you were hoping that Hibernate will map your records to objects of required class automatically than it **does not**, I tried to do the same about a year ago - you will need to create a custom (manual) mapper.
AFAIR it is a deficiency of PostgreSQL driver when using SPs.

Comment: @OkadzakiTomoe: use a `select` statement instead. Postgres doesn't have real procedures, only functions. And functions should be called using `select` (i.e. `Statement.executeQuery()` not as a "procedure" (using a `CallableStatement`)